# MVC SpringBoot and JPA Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have an issue with the JPA relationship within a MVC SpringBoot application.

I'm trying to create an application where I have a number of users and every user can have a number of cars. A user can have multiple cars. I've done a @OneToOne relationship between the user and the car object, here's what I've done:

here is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars;

}
```

then here is the Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "make", nullable = false)
    private String make;

    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

}
```

Then, here is the actual service implementation

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

@Inject
private CarRepository carRepository;

@Inject
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Car addCar(Long userId, Car car) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);      
    user.getGpsLocationModels().add(car);

    car.setUser(user);
    carRepository.save(car);

    return car;
}
```

then I have the endpoint but that works fully. The add method looks like does work as supposed to, at least I get the expected output, however the find method I have no idea how to write it, well can't figure it out how to retrieve cars based on user, I know how to get them by their ID but not for every user separately.

Here is my try:

```
@Override
public Car findCar(Long userId, Long carId) {

    //get the current user (that comes as JSON Request Param)
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);

    //get the car based on its ID, here's the problem, I want the car based on its ID AND its user, I can't display cars which aren't for that particular user
    Car car = carRepository.findOne(carId);

    return car;
}
```

Here is the method for get all cars for a particular user:

```
@Override
public List<Car> displayAllCars(Long userId) {
    return userRepository.findOne(userId).getCars();
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help that you could advise.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mappings are incorrect. Car > User is @ManyToOne. If you also make this bi-directional you can also then retrieve the cars via the user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Car> cars;

    public Set<Car> getCars(){
        return cars;
    }

    public void addCar(Car car){
        cars.add(car);
        car.setUser(this);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
}

@Override
public Set<Car> findCars(Long userId) {
    return userRepository.findOne(userId).getCars();
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you so much for your help. Please review the code above, as I've edited it. I'm getting an exception at the moment. Also, the findCars method is for getting all the cars, however, I need only one particular car for that particular user, based on car's ID or make or model (either way).  Also, I haven't made the relation @ManytoOne as I've thought every HTTP call I make, there will be one car, not multiple cars at the same call, however, the code has been amended as suggested. Thank you so much. Really much appreciated :)

Comment: Sotry but your question was answered and is now too broad.

Comment: Alright, no worries at all. At least, could you tell me if the mappings are looking good this time, from the code above? Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method that accepts the user ID and returns the list in the car repository like:

```
List<Car> findCarByUser(Long userID);
```

And then you will have

```
@Override
public List<Car> displayAllCars(Long userId) {
return carRepository.findCarByUser(userId);
}
```